# methods to forward flash webcam stream to php or language servers?

Tags: php, flash

hello i was wondering what is a good way to forward my web cam stream to my php server? I am not quite sure how to do this other than saving the video as a file and transferring it to my server or capture frame images every x amount of time and sending it to my server. i was wondering if there were other methods available other than this?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly is the intent but you might be interested in something like http://www.red5-recorder.com/

For video chat look into this http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api , I have tested this and its awesome!

Comment: thanks. i want to do livestream from my laptop to my website using flash so as to make a two way communication between users with their cams. i am having trouble understanding how i am gonna make the users see each other cameras within the website using php and flash.

Comment: @user1509326 look at my updated answer, hopefully tokbox will immediately solve all your problems.

Comment: appreciated, but it costs money =/ and i want to learn how to program flash as well. =)

Comment: @user1509326 all 2 person chats are free and 3 way for medium scale site should be covered under free license  as well http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/pricing . If you want to learn Flash programming then its a different story :)